# - (BOOL)ccTouchBegan responds on simulator but not on device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a Pause screen menu for a game. After displaying the pause screen, I have the user touch the screen to hide the pause screen and resume the game. This works perfect on the simulator but doesn't work when I test on an actual device. It seems that the device doesn't respond to touches specifically for the pause menu. Every other part of the game works fine on both the simulator and device. It's weird how it does work on the simulator but not on the device. This is the code I have for the pause screen:

```
- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {

    CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    //windowSize.height = 768.0;
    //windowSize.width = 1024.0;

    CCSprite *whiteScreen = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"OutOfTime.png"];
    whiteScreen.position = ccp(windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height / 2);
    [self addChild:whiteScreen];

    CCLabelTTF *touchToDismiss = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Touch screen to continue"     fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30];
    touchToDismiss.color = ccBLACK;

    touchToDismiss.position = ccp(windowSize.width / 2, 20);
    [self addChild:touchToDismiss];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
}

- (void)gameOverWithScore:(NSInteger)score {
    CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    //windowSize.height = 768.0;
    //windowSize.width = 1024.0;

    CCLabelTTF *touchToDismiss = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Game Over" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:75];
    touchToDismiss.color = ccBLACK;
    touchToDismiss.position = ccp(windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height / 2 + 40);
    [self addChild:touchToDismiss];

    NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final Score: %d", score];
    CCLabelTTF *scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:scoreString fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:60];
    scoreLabel.color = ccBLACK;
    scoreLabel.position = ccp(windowSize.width / 2, (windowSize.height / 2) - 40);
    [self addChild:scoreLabel];
}

- (void)setMessage:(NSString *)message {

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"haha");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add the following line on your init

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

You have to do this for every CCLayer you have that has touch events.

EDIT: just noticed that your ccTouchBegan only prints a Log.
This log is easily viewed in the debug window of XCode, but in the device it is hidden from the user.
Try doing something else.

Comment: Thanks Kurama! Actually figured what I was doing wrong. I was using
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
to pause my game. Interestingly enough the simulator still responded to touches but the device didn't!